# Cassandra NetworkTopologyStrategy

Tags: database, cluster, replication, cassandra

I would like to configure the following multi-datacenter Cassandra cluster:

- `DC-EUROPE` has 3 Cassandra nodes (`1.1.1.1`, `1.1.1.2`, `1.1.1.3`)
- `DC-ASIA` has 3 Cassandra nodes (`2.2.2.1`, `2.2.2.2`, `2.2.2.3`)
- Each DC has an eventually consistent **full-copy** (1:1) of the keyspace. Services running in `DC-EUROPE` will always query `DC-EUROPE` and services running in `DC-ASIA` will always query `DC-ASIA`.
- The data has a replication factor of `2` across the 3 nodes in each DC.

How could I setup this configuration using `NetworkTopologyStrategy` ?

Answer (score 1):

The NetworkTopologySettings needs to be specified as part of the [create keyspace](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/create_keyspace_r.html) statement.

Answer (score 1):

The correct configuration here would be the following:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE foo WITH REPLICATION = { 
   'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 
   'DC-EUROPE': 2, 
   'DC-ASIA': 2
};
```